Female character hears a song that would trigger an alternate personality
I had just watched this show within the last year it had something to do with this lady who was nice and normal then these guys show up and started singing a song that triggers her into an alternate personality I'm thinking the personality was that of her deceased sister.
When the guys started singing she kept shaking her head no because she didn't want to go to the evil personality. I think they committed some crimes once she switched and maybe had the cops puzzled because she didn't remember.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification? Any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

Reminded me of sucker punch.

Sounds like the Blacklist season 2 opener Lord Baltimore from half a year ago, in which the team goes after a woman played by Krysten Ritter who adopted her dead sister's personality and her real self is triggered by the song We Three. She doesn't remember her crimes and shakes her head reluctantly when the song is played. Here's the promo:



